# Use replace and isnull in the same select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use ISNULL and REPLACE in the same select at the end of my SP.

```
SELECT row, ISNULL(COL01,''),REPLACE(COL01,'.',',')
```

Is the way I tried it now, it doesnt work really. How to combine these two in one query?

Cheers

Comment: "doesnt work" is not a good problem description. What is the result you want to get when COL01 is/isn't null, what did you get (errors, unexpected results, ...)? Please specify by editing your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, first will be "executed" the ISNULL, so if COL01 has a NULL value then an empty string will be returned and passed to the REPLACE function, which will replace all the '.' with a ','. If the value was NULL an empty string will be returned.

```
REPLACE(ISNULL(COL01,''),'.',',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're replacement value will never contain a `.`, you can just wrap the `REPLACE` with an `ISNULL` (or [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)<sup>1</sup>):

```
SELECT row, COALESCE(REPLACE(COL01,'.',','),'')
```

[`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) with any parameter of `NULL` will just return `NULL`, you don't need to do anything to protect it.

---

<sup>1</sup> `COALESCE` is usually preferred because a) It's Standard SQL, b) It generalizes to more than two parameters, and c) It respects the normal type precedence rules. `ISNULL` on the other hand is non-standard, can only be called with two parameters, and (if it uses the second parameter) forces the second parameter to be converted to the same type as the first parameter.

The only place I'd recommend using `ISNULL` rather than `COALESCE` is when you're creating a computed column in a table or within a view, the second parameter you're passing is non-NULL, and you want the column's definition in metadata to be `not null`.